# Is SteamOS frame-rate performance related to X11?

Tags: x11, xorg, nvidia, graphics, steam

Ars recently tested SteamOS against Windows 10 and [determined on average Windows 10 had a higher frame rate](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2015/11/ars-benchmarks-show-significant-performance-hit-for-steamos-gaming/?comments=1&start=40).

Does this have anything to do with Linux's reliance on an archaic graphics system (X11)?

Comment: @don_crissti Not looking for any nVidia support. I don't even use SteamOS. Only looking for a valid answer if the Linux X system is a potential cause of this drop.

Comment: I guess this is the graphics driver issue.  You may take a look at http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=nvidia-win10-ubuntu15&num=1

Comment: @OttToomet, that is a good find. As the original question suggests, there may be a reason for any potential inferior Linux graphics performance (in comparison to Windows 10), and that reason is the X system. (Currently searching for a link to that long well detailed post/answer somewhere here on the StackExchange universe describing the performance limitations of X...)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that Nvidia drivers bypass X system almost entirely, in a similar way as Mesa drivers use [DRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Infrastructure).

You will be able to measure the X11 overhead (if any) [once Nvidia starts to support Wayland in their drivers](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=nvidia-355.06-linux-beta).